# error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000040) "extern "C

Tags: c++

am new to the world of C++ until now i was doin only java ,i have an application in which am implementing some of the functionalities of libusb.h, when i run build the appliction an error comes out as shown below

> 1>AOA.obj : error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000040) "extern "C" int
>   __stdcall libusb_get_config_descriptor(struct libusb_device *,unsigned char,struct libusb_config_descriptor * *)"
>   (?libusb_get_config_descriptor@@$$J212YGHPAUlibusb_device@@EPAPAUlibusb_config_descriptor@@@Z)
>   referenced in function "private: int __stdcall
>   AOA::findEndPoint(struct libusb_device *)"
>   (?findEndPoint@AOA@@$$FAAGHPAUlibusb_device@@@Z)

Thanks.

Comment: are you linking the libusb library?

Comment: @suspectus - thx for ur reply as i mentioned am new to c++,  cud u pls tell me how to do it. thx.

Comment: @AbhishekThayyil: Maybe, as you're asking for help, you could put the effort required into writing words out in full. It only takes a moment. Thanks.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - Thanks for the advice i will keep that in mind henceforth :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to link against libusb. You should add `-lusb` to the gcc call. You might need to add `-Lpath_to_libusb` before `-lusb`.

Maybe you better should start with a given sample program like [that one](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/tree/master/examples)?

Comment: You are amazing @WernerHenze you have saved my life